# useEffect infinite loop occurs even when second dependency exists

Tags: reactjs, state, use-effect

```
const [hanziList, sethanziList] = useState([]);

const [whetherFinish, setWhetherFinish] = useState()

const inspectCheckboxList = () => {

        var i = 0;
        while (i < hanziList.length) {
            if (hanziList[i].memorize === 0) {
                setWhetherFinish("notFinish")
                break;
            }
            if (hanziList[i].memorize === 1) {
                i = i + 1;
            }
            if (i === hanziList.length) {
                setWhetherFinish("finish")
            }
                console.log(whetherFinish)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => { inspectCheckboxList(); }, [hanziList]);
```

`hanziList` is an object which came from MySQL, it is a list of Chinese voca. and on List, if I check checkbox then the value of `memorize` turns into 1. So, 0 means not memorized, 1 means memorized.

If I check all of the checkboxes, it means that I have memorized all of the voca on the list, so the `className` of a button changes from "notFinish" into "finish".

And to check whether it is "finish", I made a function `inspectCheckboxList`. Every time the value of `memorize` changes, by `useEffect` render the function.

I found that putting state inside `useEffect` is a way to solve the problem, but it is not possible for me.

I'm not sure why the infinite loop occurs, because by `useEffect`, the function only renders when the website first laods, and the value of `memorize (in this case,` hanziList`) changes.

I think this is because inside function concludes `hanziList`, and the second dependency is also `hanziList`.

Why does the infinite loop occur, even when I set second dependency, and how to solve this problem?

Comment: that's not really a react issue looking at it, the problem is that your while loop seems to be set up to go infinitely because you only increment `i` if the second if statement is true -> are you sure that `memorize` can only be 1 or 0

Comment: I will check if there is any value. thanks for help.

Comment: Yes you are correct! I did not know if click around the checkbox gives undefined.